# Pushing messages through the REST interface of HornetQ

Tags: hornetq

I'm working with the REST interface of the Hornetq 2.2.5 version, running as the JMS provider of a JBoss-4.2.1 GA application server. I've successfully deployed a .war, which has the HornetQ REST messaging interface. I can send messages properly, using the resources of the app. Now, I'm trying to push messages to a remote REST resource, so I sent a HEAD request, got the msg-push-consumers header and sent the following POST request:

```
<push-registration>  
   <link href="http://remotehost:8081/TestREST/webresources/test" method="PUT" />
</push-registration>
```

I reviewed the JBoss log and read:

> 18:04:20,953 INFO  [PushConsumer] Push consumer started for:
>   XmlLink{className='null', rel='null',
>   href='http://remotehost:8081/TestREST/webresources/test', type='null',
>   method='PUT'}

But, when I try to send a JMS test message to the queue, I got the following exception:

> 18:07:08,234 ERROR [ClientConsumerImpl] Failed to call onMessage()
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>             at org.jboss.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer.checkReadableBytes(AbstractChannelBuffer.java:657)
>             at org.jboss.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer.readBytes(AbstractChannelBuffer.java:337)
>             at org.jboss.netty.buffer.AbstractChannelBuffer.readBytes(AbstractChannelBuffer.java:343)
>             at org.hornetq.core.buffers.impl.ChannelBufferWrapper.readBytes(ChannelBufferWrapper.java:347)
>             at org.hornetq.rest.util.HttpMessageHelper.buildMessage(HttpMessageHelper.java:97)
>             at org.hornetq.rest.queue.push.UriStrategy.push(UriStrategy.java:82)
>             at org.hornetq.rest.queue.push.PushConsumer.onMessage(PushConsumer.java:114)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:866)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:44)
>             at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983)
>             at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Do you have any idea to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the latest versions first? There were several changes. I would recommend 2.2.14

Then we can look into a possible bug. We will need a replicator to your issue.